# Problem With Public IP

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I feel like this can be easily solved but im too dumb to get it so let me just fill you on with my problem, my server is behind a router which i have put a static IP for it and opened some ports for it.

Ive configured OpenVPN and done Samba Share. But whatever I do I can not ping my public IP and my Openvpn does not work at home, one dumb solution I found is to connect to some other vpn and then connect to openvpn from there, and that works like a charm.

I haven't tested it trying to connect from somewhere else becuase I was busy these past few weeks, at my school they filtered vpn's and I cant connect there.

I also have enabled UFW and I connect to my server with ssh using a certificate ID.

My only question is that why cant I ping or communicate to my server's public IP at my own house?

Comment: @user68186 Even though the accepted answer provided by OP indicates issues with the router, not Ubuntu, I voted to leave this question open because its answer may be generally useful to the Ubuntu community anyway.

Comment: @karel fair enough. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some routers wont let you reach your public IP at home. My ones one of those cases. I ended up testing my server by connecting to data and connect to the vpn server.

Answer (score 0):

You're behind a [Carrier-Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). ISPs do this to scale their services and avoid IP address exhaustion.

This makes it impossible(?) to host services on your end.

Comment: I use to host game servers using portforwarding and they could connect to me, recently it dosn't work. Is there anyway around this?